# How can i adapt multivariate normal for batch operations?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, matrix, numpy

I am implementing from scratch the multivariate normal probability function in python. The formula for it is as follows:

[image: mvnp]

I was able to code this version, where $\mathbf{x}$ is an input vector (single sample). However, i could make good use of numpy's matrix operations and extend it to the case of using $\mathbf{X}$ (set of samples) to return all the samples probabilities at once. This is equal to the [scipy's implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html).

This is the code i have made:

```py
def multivariate_normal(X, center, cov):
    k = X.shape[0]
    
    det_cov = np.linalg.det(cov)
    inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov)

    o = 1 / np.sqrt( (2 * np.pi) ** k  * det_cov)
    p = np.exp( -.5 * ( np.dot(np.dot((X - center).T, inv_cov),  (X - center))))
    return o * p
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question?